# PETSC time stepping under mpirun mode

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi, numerical-methods, finite-element-analysis, petsc

---

Dear all,
I'm a freshman in learning PETSC. I wrote a very simple 1D diffusion problem code based on PETSC library(Just simple FDM code). I want to use PETSC's parallel solver in each time step. Here is the pseudo code:

```
Initial(C0);
for(timestep=0;timestep<MaxTimeStep;timestep++)
{
    Assemble(A,C,F);  // Assemble system's A*C=F matrix and vector
    KSP.solve(A,C,F); // Use PETSC's ksp solver to solve A*C=F
                      // I just want to make the solve step paralleled
                      // other part don't need to be paralleled
    C0=C;             // Update
    SaveResult(C0);   // Output the result C0
}
```

This code works very fine under sequential mode(the matrix and vector are both based on the MPI type), but when I try to use mpirun -np 4 ./a.out, the result is totally wrong. I guess mpirun make the timestep loop also paralleled, but I'm not sure about it.

So, my problem are:

1. How to use PETSC's parallel solver inside a loop, or in other words, how to use parallel solver or mpirun inside a sequential time stepping?
2. Is it possible that I can use `mpirun -np 4 ./myapp` to just parallel the solver, but for the time stepping and result output,they are still sequential? In the simulation, time stepping and result output must be executed one by one, so I just need to parallel the solver, not the whole program.

Thank you!

```
#include "petscksp.h"

void PrintToVTU(PetscInt k,PetscReal dx,Vec u);


int main(int argc,char **args)
{
    Vec u,u0;
    Mat A;
    KSP ksp;
  PetscRandom rctx;
  PetscReal norm;
  PetscInt ne;
  PetscReal Length,dx,D;
  PetscReal Ca,Cb,alpha;
  PetscReal T,dt,ti;
  PetscInt i,j,Ii,J,Istart,Iend,m,n,its;
  PetscBool flg=PETSC_FALSE;
  PetscScalar v;

  printf("Input the Length:");
  scanf("%f",&Length);
  printf("Input the element number:");
  scanf("%d",&ne);
  printf("Input the Ca,Cb and D:");
  scanf("%f %f %f",&Ca,&Cb,&D);
  printf("Input dt and T:");
  scanf("%f %f",&dt,&T);
  n=ne+1;m=n;
  dx=Length/ne;

  alpha=dt*D/(dx*dx);

  #if defined(PETSC_USE_LOG)
   PetscLogStage stage;
  #endif

  static char help[] = "Solves a linear system in parallel with 
  KSP.\n\
  Iput parameters include:\n-random_exact_sol : use a random exact 
  solution vector\n\
 -view_exact_sol   : write exact solution vector to stdout\n\
 -m <mesh_x>       : number of mesh points in x-direction\n\
 -n <mesh_n>       : number of mesh points in y-direction\n\n";
 PetscInitialize(&argc,&args,(char*)0,help);
 PetscOptionsGetInt(NULL,NULL,"-m",&m,NULL);

 PetscOptionsGetInt(NULL,NULL,"-n",&n,NULL);
 printf("m=%d\tn=%d\n",m,n);


// Create Matrix
MatCreate(PETSC_COMM_WORLD,&A);
MatSetSizes(A,PETSC_DECIDE,PETSC_DECIDE,m,n);
MatSetFromOptions(A);
MatMPIAIJSetPreallocation(A,5,NULL,5,NULL);
MatSeqAIJSetPreallocation(A,5,NULL);
MatSeqSBAIJSetPreallocation(A,1,5,NULL);
// Create Vector
VecCreate(PETSC_COMM_WORLD,&u0);
VecSetSizes(u0,PETSC_DECIDE,m);
VecSetFromOptions(u0);
VecDuplicate(u0,&u);

MatGetOwnershipRange(A,&Istart,&Iend);

PetscLogStageRegister("Assembly",&stage);
PetscLogStagePush(stage);

for(Ii=Istart;Ii<Iend;Ii++)
{
    if(Ii==0)
    {
        v=1.0+2.0*alpha;J=Ii;
        MatSetValues(A,1,&Ii,1,&J,&v,ADD_VALUES);

        v=-2.0*alpha;J=Ii+1;
        MatSetValues(A,1,&Ii,1,&J,&v,ADD_VALUES);
    }
    else if(Ii==n-1)
    {
        v=-2.0*alpha;J=Ii-1;
        MatSetValues(A,1,&Ii,1,&J,&v,ADD_VALUES);

        v=1.0+2.0*alpha;J=Ii;
        MatSetValues(A,1,&Ii,1,&J,&v,ADD_VALUES);
    }
    else
    {
        v=-alpha;J=Ii-1;
        MatSetValues(A,1,&Ii,1,&J,&v,ADD_VALUES);

        v=1.0+2.0*alpha;J=Ii;
        MatSetValues(A,1,&Ii,1,&J,&v,ADD_VALUES);

        v=-alpha;J=Ii+1;
        MatSetValues(A,1,&Ii,1,&J,&v,ADD_VALUES);
    }
    if(Ii<=m/2)
    {
        VecSetValues(u0,1,&Ii,&Ca,ADD_VALUES);
    }
    else
    {
        VecSetValues(u0,1,&Ii,&Cb,ADD_VALUES);
    }
}
MatAssemblyBegin(A,MAT_FINAL_ASSEMBLY);
MatAssemblyEnd(A,MAT_FINAL_ASSEMBLY);
VecAssemblyBegin(u0);
VecAssemblyEnd(u0);

KSPCreate(PETSC_COMM_WORLD,&ksp);
KSPSetOperators(ksp,A,A);
KSPSetFromOptions(ksp);



dt=1.0;T=2.0;i=0;
PrintToVTU(i,dx,u0);
printf("Hello\n");
for(ti=0.0;ti<=T;ti+=dt)
{
    i+=1;
    KSPSolve(ksp,u0,u);
    VecCopy(u,u0);
    PrintToVTU(i,dx,u0);
}
}
```

Comment: Please upload a minimal complete code to work on.

Comment: @Shibli: Hi, thank you sincerely for the reply. I add my code inside the question.

Comment: Sorry actually a minimal code was not needed, my bad. For these kind of problems use time-steppers of PETSC. Here are [sequential](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/petsc-current/src/ts/examples/tutorials/ex3.c.html) and [parallel](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/petsc-current/src/ts/examples/tutorials/ex4.c.html) examples for 1D diffusion problem. If you get stuck at any point let me know so that we can sort it out in the chat. Regarding your two questions, AFAIK, no you cannot.

Comment: Hi Shibli, thanks for the reply. I know the TS fuctions, the TS timestepper. What makes me confused is, if there are some other loops outside the TS timestepper on the other place of my code(For example the mesh generating, which I want it to be executed sequentially not paralleled), is it possible? Or, in PETSc, the TS is the only choice which can ensure these loops be executed one by one, except that all the loop code will be executed parallely?

Comment: Mesh generation can be carried out by a specific rank with conditional such as `if (rank == MASTER)`. One of the merits of Petsc is that it takes care of parallelism. So whenever you find yourself in the situation you mentioned, take a look at Petsc documentation to find a suitable context.